# USB ports stop working randomly Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, usb, mouse, dell, power-management

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS only 6 months and I started to notice that my USB ports stop working randomly without no reason. My mouse still flickers, but the pointer on the screen can not be moved with it. Flash cards are not recognized as well as a phone.
When I try to run lsusb command it shows nothing, it just looks like it`s loading forever.

As I have read it may be connected to the power management. Usually, when I take off the charger USB ports stop working.

My computer is Dell Inspiron 15 (3000 Series): Core i3 2.3 GHz, 4 GB RAM, Hard drive - 500 GB. Battery capacity: 2.2 Ah

I would be very grateful for any kind of help!!

Comment: It seems to be hardware related. Please [edit] and post the hardware specs.

Comment: @MichaelBay I added some hardware details. Should I add more details?

Comment: Not that old, but it can be the hardware starting to fail, hopefully not. You can try booting a live session to test and rule out (or not) software.

Comment: But I don`t have where to boot from. Ubuntu was pre-installed when I bought a laptop

Comment: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0

Comment: Is your Ubuntu fully updated? Forgot to ask... If not do it before anything else.

Comment: No, it`s not updated. You mean, that I should update to 16.04?

Comment: No, I mean updated *within* 14.04 which is still supported. You can try newer releases but not a requirement. Just in case do, in terminal, `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.

Comment: Ok, thanks, Now my Ubuntu is fully updated, so I`ll try to boot a live session.